# Cannot access Database when put Neo4j in private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-elb

I have a question for deploying neo4j to AWS. 
Please refer to:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/cannot-access-database-when-put-neo4j-in-private-subnet/10058

Comment: Sorry to share the link, because I want to have pictures to explain my question

Answer (score 1):

Where is database placed? do you use RDS for database or hosting database in the same ec2 machine. In case if your database is in the RDS, make sure that the RDS lies in the same vpc as your ec2. If not you should make a VPC peering connection with the vpc of your RDS.